# Text data sharing on Facebook in android

Tags: android, android-intent, share

i want to share a text data on Facebook wall.using ACTION_SEND.

```
                Intent sendIntent = new Intent();
            sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "This is my text to send.");
            sendIntent.setType("text/plain");
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sendIntent, "Share"));
```

text is shared on all apps(Twitter,messages,emails) but not on Facebook wall.when i click on Facebook icon from popup window, Facebook page open but text data that I want to share is not visible on Facebook Editbox(post to wall).Empty editbox of Facebook wall appears.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Facebook app enforce this— if you try to share something with pre-filled in text (put extra) , app doesn't know if it was written by the user or filled in by the app, so according to its policy, it makes no assumptions, ignores that text, and requires the user to write the text.

[Check their privacy policy](https://developers.facebook.com/policy/#integration), in

> IV. Application Integration Points
>
> 1. [...]
> 2. **You must not pre-fill any of the fields associated with the following products, unless the user manually generated the content earlier in the workflow**: Stream stories (user_message parameter for Facebook.streamPublish and FB.Connect.streamPublish, and message parameter for stream.publish), Photos (caption), Videos (description), Notes (title and content), Links (comment), and Jabber/XMPP.